# why child pom create a new version？

Tags: java, maven, parent-pom, apache-dubbo

1. Parent pom code

   ```
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>SpringCloudDemo</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <name>SpringCloudDemo</name>
       <description>SpringCloudDemo</description>
       <packaging>pom</packaging>

       <dependencyManagement>
           <dependencies>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.dubbo</groupId>
                   <artifactId>dubbo-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                   <version>${spring-boot-dubbo.version}</version>
                   <type>pom</type>
                   <scope>import</scope>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.dubbo</groupId>
                   <artifactId>dubbo</artifactId>
                   <version>${spring-boot-dubbo.version}</version>
                   <type>pom</type>
                   <scope>import</scope>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.dubbo</groupId>
                   <artifactId>dubbo-registry-nacos</artifactId>
                   <version>${spring-boot-dubbo-nacos.version}</version>
                   <type>pom</type>
                   <scope>import</scope>
               </dependency>


           </dependencies>
       </dependencyManagement>
   ```
2. in child pom ，child extends parent pom In Child POM

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>SpringCloudDemo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.dubbo</groupId>
            <artifactId>dubbo-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.dubbo</groupId>
            <artifactId>dubbo</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Nacos依赖 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.dubbo</groupId>
            <artifactId>dubbo-registry-nacos</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

3. But my child pom download 2.7.4.1 version，no use Parent Pom 3.1.9 Version dubbo，like picture
4. I have one questions:

I want use 3.1.9 Version Dubbo ,But In Child Pom download 2.7.4.1 Version Dubbo？what happening？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem could be in defining dependencies in the `<dependentManagement/>` section in the parent `pom`. For example:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.dubbo</groupId>
            <artifactId>dubbo-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-dubbo.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type> <!-- wrong -->
            <scope>import</scope> <!-- wrong -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The `<type/>` and `</scope>` are incorrect, beacuse the `dubbo-spring-boot-starter` dependency isn't of type `pom` and you didn't should to define the scope as `import`.

According to [official docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope), the `import` scope is only relevant for depepndencies with type `pom`:

> This scope is only supported on a dependency of type `pom` in the `<dependencyManagement>` section. It indicates the dependency is to be replaced with the effective list of dependencies in the specified POM's `<dependencyManagement>` section. Since they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of `import` do not actually participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

Try to remove the type and scope from all dependencies in the `<dependentManagement/>` section in the parent `pom`.

It is just a guess.